# AlwaysOn Availability Groups Support msdtc

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, msdtc, alwayson

I have to work with AlwaysOn Availability Groups with msdtc.It's not work for me.after searching i read [Cross-Database Transactions Not Supported For Database Mirroring or AlwaysOn Availability Groups (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366279.aspx).My question is AlwaysOn Availability Groups Support msdtc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in the current version of SQL Server. This has been a big customer ask, so the next version SQL 2016 will support it.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported by SQL 2012 but it is available with SQL 2016. Go on and dig 2016 :)

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported in SQL Server 2016 SP2!